# Parsing XML file to CSV with as little hard-coding as possible

Tags: xml, csv

I would like to parse through the xml and get tags with as little hard-coding as possible and convert to CSV

I will need to hard-code these specific column names:
'InfoGroup', 'InfoRegister', 'RegisterType', 'Measures', 'Description', 'GeneratedOn'

InfoGroup are the name tags like RecordingSystem, Ports, etc

InfoRegister is the sub name located inside the row tags like closedFileCount, processedFileCount, etc

RegisterType is the tag name where the sub name is located like , , , etc

Measures is just the measures tag

Description is just the description tag

GeneratedOn is located inside the generatedOn tag like sessmgr, rtpportal, etc

If there are any other or new tags in the xml I would like it to be able to add it to the csv automatically.

The current implementation I have is all basically hard-coded but I couldn't get it to function otherwise. Please run the code with my xml to see how the CSV should actually look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<infoconfig xmlns="urn:nortel:namespaces:mcp:oms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:nortel:namespaces:mcp:oms OMSchema.xsd" >

        <group>
                <name>RecordingSystem</name>
                <row>
                        <package>com.nortelnetworks.mcp.ne.base.recsystem.fw.system</package>
                        <class>RecSysFileOMRow</class>
                        <usage name="closedFileCount" hasThresholds="true">
                                <measures>
                                        closed file count
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        This register counts the number
                                        of closed files in the spool directory of a
                                        particular stream and a particular system.
                                        Files in the spool directory store the raw
                                        OAM records where they are sent to the
                                        Element Manager for formatting.
                                </description>
                                <notes>
                                        Minor and major alarms
                                        when the value of closedFileCount
                                        exceeds certain thresholds. Configure
                                        the threshold values for minor and major
                                        alarms for this OM through engineering
                                        parameters for minorBackLogCount and
                                        majorBackLogCount, respectively. These
                                        engineering parameters are grouped under
                                        the parameter group of Log, OM, and
                                        Accounting for the logs’ corresponding
                                        system.
                                </notes>
                        </usage>
                        <usage name="processedFileCount" hasThresholds="true">
                                <measures>
                                        Processed file count
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        The register counts the number
                                        of processed files in the spool directory of
                                        a particular stream and a particular system.
                                        Files in the spool directory store the raw
                                        OAM records and then send the records to
                                        the Element Manager for formatting.
                                </description>
                        </usage>
                </row>
                <documentation>
                        <description>
                                Rows of this OM group provide a count of the number of files contained
                                within the directory (which is the OM row key value).
                        </description>
                        <rowKey>
                                The full name of the directory containing the files counted by this row.
                        </rowKey>
                </documentation>
                <generatedOn>
                        <all/>
                </generatedOn>
        </group>
        <group traffic="true">
                <name>Ports</name>
                <row>
                        <package>com.nortelnetworks.ims.cap.mediaportal.host</package>
                        <class>PortsOMRow</class>
                        <usage name="rtpMpPortUsage">
                                <measures>
                                        BCP port usage
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        Meter showing number of ports in use.
                                </description>
                        </usage>
                        <lwGauge name="connMapEntriesLWM">
                                <measures>
                                        Lowest simultaneous port usage
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        Lowest number of
                                        simultaneous ports detected to be in
                                        use during the collection interval
                                </description>
                        </lwGauge>
                        <hwGauge name="connMapEntriesHWM">
                                <measures>
                                        Highest simultaneous port usage
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        Highest number of
                                        simultaneous ports detected to be in
                                        use during the collection interval.
                                </description>
                        </hwGauge>
                        <waterMark name="connMapEntries">
                                <measures>
                                        Connections map entries
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                        Meter showing the number of connections in the host
                                        CPU connection map.
                                </description>
                                <bwg lwref="connMapEntriesLWM" hwref="connMapEntriesHWM"/>
                        </waterMark>
                        <counter name="portUsageSampleCnt">
                                <measures>
                                    Usage sample count
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                    The number of 100-second samples taken during the
                                    collection interval contributing to the average report.
                                </description>
                        </counter>
                        <counter name="sampledRtpMpPortUsage">
                                <measures>
                                    In-use ports usage
                                </measures>
                                <description>
                                    Provides the sum of the in-use ports every 100 seconds.
                                </description>
                        </counter>
                        <precollector>
                                <package>com.nortelnetworks.ims.cap.mediaportal.host</package>
                                <class>PortsOMCenturyPrecollector</class>
                                <collector>centurySecond</collector>
                        </precollector>
                </row>
                <documentation>
                        <description>
                        </description>
                        <rowKey>
                        </rowKey>
                </documentation>
                <generatedOn>
                        <list>
                            <ne>sessmgr</ne>
                            <ne>rtpportal</ne>
                        </list>
                </generatedOn>
        </group>
        <group traffic="true">
            <name>SASIPPBXTrunkGroupCallMgmt</name>
            <row>
                <package>com.nortelnetworks.ims.cap.svc.sippbx.fsm</package>
                <class>StandAloneSipPbxTrunkGroupOMRow</class>
                <hwGauge name="callAttemptsHighForOrigination">
                    <measures></measures>
                    <description></description>
                </hwGauge>
                <waterMark name="callAttemptsForOrigination">
                    <measures> Number of Call attempts </measures>
                    <description>> This counter will keep track of incoming call attempts of Trunk Group  to or from a SIPPBX node </description>
                    <bwg lwref="callAttemptsLowForOrigination" hwref="callAttemptsHighForOrigination"/>
                </waterMark>
                <lwGauge name="callAttemptsLowForOrigination">
                    <measures></measures>
                    <description></description>
                </lwGauge>  
                <hwGauge name="callAttemptsHighForTermination">
                    <measures></measures>
                    <description></description>
                </hwGauge>
                <waterMark name="callAttemptsForTermination">
                    <measures> Number of Call attempts </measures>
                    <description>> This counter will keep track of outgoing call attempts of Trunk Group  to or from a SIPPBX node </description>
                    <bwg lwref="callAttemptsLowForTermination" hwref="callAttemptsHighForTermination"/>
                </waterMark>
                <lwGauge name="callAttemptsLowForTermination">
                    <measures></measures>
                    <description></description>
                </lwGauge>  
                <hwGauge name="activeCallsHighForOrigination">
                    <measures></measures>
                    <description></description>
                </hwGauge>
                <waterMark name="activeCallsForOrigination">
                    <measures> Number of Incoming Active calls </measures>
                    <description>> This counter will keep track of incoming active call of Trunk Group  to or from a SIPPBX node </description>
                    <bwg lwref="activeCallsLowForOrigination" hwref="activeCallsHighForOrigination"/>
                </waterMark>
                <lwGauge name="activeCallsLowForOrigination">
                    <measures></measures>
                    <description></description>
                </lwGauge>  
                <hwGauge name="activeCallsHighForTermination">
                    <measures></measures>
                    <description></description>
                </hwGauge>
                <waterMark name="activeCallsForTermination">
                    <measures> Number of Outgoing Active calls </measures>
                    <description>> This counter will keep track of outgoing call active call of Trunk Group  to or from a SIPPBX node </description>
                    <bwg lwref="activeCallsLowForTermination" hwref="activeCallsHighForTermination"/>
                </waterMark>
                <lwGauge name="activeCallsLowForTermination">
                    <measures></measures>
                    <description></description>
                </lwGauge>  
                <counter name="deniedCallsDueToCapacityForOrigination">
                    <measures>Number of Denied Calls due to capacity </measures>
                    <description>This counter will keep track denied for incoming call attempts of Trunk Group  to or from a SIPPBX node </description>
                </counter>
                <counter name="deniedCallsDueToCapacityForTermination">
                    <measures>Number of Denied Calls due to capacity </measures>
                    <description>This counter will keep track denied for outgoing call attempts of Trunk Group  to or from a SIPPBX node </description>
                </counter>
                <counter name="failoverRouteCallAttempts">
                    <measures>Number of FailOverRoute Call  attempts </measures>
                    <description>This counter will keep track of FailOverRoute Call attempts of Trunk Group  for a SIPPBX node </description>
                </counter>
            </row>
            <documentation>
                <description></description>
                <rowKey></rowKey>
            </documentation>
            <generatedOn>
                <list>
                    <ne>sessmgr</ne>
                </list>
            </generatedOn>
        </group>
       
</infoconfig>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv



def extract_data_from_report3():
    xmlfile = open('infoconfig.xml', 'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xmlfile, 'lxml')

    with open('data2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
        writer = csv.writer(f_out)
        writer.writerow(['InfoGroup:InfoRegister', 'InfoGroup', 'InfoRegister', 'RegisterType', 'Measures', 'Description', 'GeneratedOn'])


        for item in soup.select('row [name]'):
            desc = getattr(item.find('description'), 'text', None)
            desc= str(desc)
            desc = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', desc)
            generatedOn = ','.join(ne.get_text(strip=True) for ne in item.find_parent('group').select('ne'))

            writer.writerow([item.find_previous('name').text + ':' + item['name'], item.find_previous('name').text, item['name'], item.name, item.find('measures').get_text(strip=True), desc, generatedOn])

        print("File successfuly converted to CSV")
```

**Screenshot of the issue**
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't understood your requirement yet. I'll see it tomorrow.

Comment: @yazz Appreciate it, thank you. If you need me to clarify anything let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still don't understand the rules of the other new tags you mentioned, but I rewrite it according to your current logic. We can further communicate on this basis to finally achieve the results you want.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils


def extract_data_from_report3():

    header = [
        'InfoGroup:InfoRegister', 'InfoGroup', 'InfoRegister', 'RegisterType', 'GeneratedOn' # edit
    ]
    datas = []
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(utils.getFileContent('infoconfig.xml'))
    groups = doc.selects('group')
    for group in groups:
        name = group.select('name>text()')
        # generatedOn = ','.join(group.selects('generatedOn>ne>text()'))
        # edit start...
        all = group.select('generatedOn').child
        if not all.child: 
            generatedOn = all.tag
        else:
            generatedOn = ','.join(all.selects('ne>text()'))
        # edit end...

        RegisterTypes = group.row.children.containsReg(
            '.+', attr='name')  # The node with the name attribute.
        for registerType in RegisterTypes:
            extr = {}
            for c in registerType.children:
                if c['tag'] not in header:
                    header.append(c['tag'])
                extr[c['tag']] = c.text # edit
                
            datas.append([
                '{}:{}'.format(name, registerType['name']), name,
                registerType['name'], registerType['tag'], generatedOn, extr])
    
    rows = [header]
    for data in datas:
        row = data[:-1]
        extr = data[-1]
        for i in range(5,len(header)): # edit
            row.append(extr.get(header[i]))

        rows.append(row)

    utils.save2csv('data.csv', rows, newline='')


extract_data_from_report3()
```

Comment: Thanks @yazz for this implementation but it doesn't seem that it's getting all the data. I updated my XML with another group at the end, so when you run it with your code you could see that some of the rows are missing

Comment: What I meant by new tags is if for example there is a new tag that I add to the XML underneath the <description> tag. I would like the script to be able to find it and make a new column and row for it without hard-coding.

Comment: @joe_sanders I have updated the answer, please try again.

Comment: Thank you, but some of the columns are empty even though they should have data. Please look at the screenshot I added to see the missing columns. Thanks again @yazz

Comment: @joe_sanders Sorry, I made a few mistakes. Now it's modified, you can try again.

Comment: Thank you it works great. In the generatedOn, for the tags that says  <all/>, can I put the word "all" in the cell instead of it being blank?

Comment: @joe_sanders I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, I made a change, you can try it.